# Why would `symbol-name' return a fontified string?

Tags: text-properties, symbols

I've got a weird bug in a GraphQL encoder I'm writing that I've tracked down to one form:

```lisp
(symbol-name 'world)

;; yields
#("world" 0 5
  (fontified t))
```

I can reproduce the issue in a `*scratch*` buffer in that same emacs session and with `M-:`, but it's not reproducible in a new emacs session (e.g., `emacs -nw -Q`).

This doesn't happen with all symbols; `(symbol-name 'hello)` yields just `"hello"`.

---

The following snippet can reproduce the issue, but I still have no idea what would be using `make-symbol` in this way.

```lisp
(let ((sym (make-symbol (let ((s "hello world"))
                          (set-text-properties 0 (length s) '(test property) s)
                          s))))
  (symbol-name sym))
```

Comment: Considering that you can't reproduce this problem in a new Emacs instance without your init file loaded, it could be the problem. Try building the minimal case with this problem with minimal configuration.

Comment: If it were that simple, I would've done so (and probably wouldn't have needed to ask the Q) :-) I know from the C source that `symbol-name` is just retrieving the `name` property (a `Lisp_Object`) from the symbol (passing through macro `XSYMBOL`) which would leave me to believe the name was somehow fontified when the `world` symbol was interned (possibly when read), but I can't seem to validate that.

Comment: As you know, the value of `symbol-name` is a string, and strings in Emacs Lisp can have text properties. Look for a use of `make-symbol` or `intern` that receives a propertized string as argument. Note that the Lisp reader creates and interns symbols when it reads.

Comment: @Drew thanks :-) I think all name-setting for lisp objects is funneled through `set_symbol_name` which in turn is only called by `init_symbol` which is exposed in `make-symbol` and indeed called in `lread.c:define_symbol`. The lisp object `define_symbol` passes to `init_symbol` as `name` is a plain old `char *` run through `alloc.c:make_pure_c_string`. At that point, it seems unlikely that we'd just be adding text properties arbitrarily, so I'm *guessing* there's some wacky use of `make-symbol` going on somewhere.

Comment: And indeed, `(let ((sym (make-symbol (let ((s "hello world")) (set-text-properties 0 (length s) '(test property) s) s)))) (symbol-name sym))` can reproduce the issue, but I still have no idea what would be using `make-symbol` in this way.

Comment: Also asked recently here: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/7a976a/face_applied_to_result_of_symbolname_becomes/

Answer (score 2):

The function `symbol-at-point` do such thing.

And it can be used in extensions of modes like `auto-complete` or `font-lock` or anywhere else for parse buffer.
And in this case, each time, when it will be apply to point on symbol which is not yet interned, it will intern 
this symbol with all text properties.